# flutterfire firestore addAll method

Tags: flutter

if I have a csv file of 1000 list and I wanna add all of them to firebase cloud firestore
the obvious option is to call forEach and give it => FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Products').add(blablabla)
but it would take too much time, is there a better approach to do this because I can't find a method of 'addAll' or something on firestore docs

Comment: I'm afraid there is no easy way to import CSV / JHSON files in Firestore. Why do you say it would take too much time?

Comment: to be honest I didn't try it yet, I should of said "I think it would take too much time", I mean looping for 1000 item and make a request for each one!, even for a fast internet I imagine it will take too much time, I mean it should 

Comment: You'd be surprised. Give it a try. And if really it's too slow. You can write your documents by batches (max 500 docs per batch) as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#node.js

Comment: I've another question if it's okay with you,  I wanna show a loading indicator for the user during adding these docs but I can't get the progress for this process, is there a way to do that?

Comment: I would use a callback function that you call either after each document write or after each batch write.